# How can I access to a file exists on remote machine?

Tags: java, file

I want to access to a file (read) that exist on a remote machine from my code JAVA,what I need to do that?
just the IP of the machine and the location of the file or I need somthing else?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are some choices:

- Via a 'mapped' directory using SMB/Samba to the remote machine and you can then access the file using the normal `File` class.
- Via a Web Server where read access is easier (if you require write access then you are looking at something like WebDAV).  This requires the use of the HTTP protocol in your code.
- Via `FTP` or `SFTP` network protocols to access the file.  This obviously requires the use of (S)FTP classes to access the file.

The first option is easiest from a coding point-of-view.

Answer (score 2):

If both the Java code and the remote file are on Linux machines, you can also choose NFS.

1. As always you need to start a server which serves the file - you need nfsd to share the directory containing that file on the remote machine.
2. On the machine where your Java code will run, mount the shared nfs

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ubuntu-linux-nfs-client-configuration-to-mount-nfs-share.html) is a brief introduction of using nfs on Ubuntu.

If you prefer FTP/HTTP, you will be interested in [Apache commons vfs](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) library, which supports many protocols including FTP, SFTP, HTTP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a service on the remote machine that serves files.  Once a file-serving service exists, you communicate with the service using its protocol.

Assuming the [client-server model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model), you have several choices on the remote (server) side.  First of all, you can design your own protocol, write a server, deploy it on the remote machine and write a client (in Java) which will talk with the server using the designed protocol.  However, there many off-the-shelf solutions (protocols + servers + Java client libraries) that might be used.  Three protocols which come to mind right now: [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol), [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) and [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).

If your aim is simplicity, I recommend TFTP: there are free TFTP servers for UNIX, Windows and Mac OS X, and there is [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) Java library on the client side.